# Генерация всех возможных комбинаций из пар элементов

Tags: алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика

у меня есть пары:

```
A-B, B-C, A-C
```

Как мне на выходе получить все возможные комбинации по 4 элемента так, чтобы первый и последний элемент были одинаковыми?

```
A-B-C-A, A-C-B-A, C-A-B-C, B-A-C-B и т д
```

Интересует не реализация в виде кода, а сам алгоритм, если вдруг имеете реализацию, поделитесь, пожалуйста, не откажусь.

В целом есть мысль брать каждый из элементов пары (уникальный) как первый и последний элементы массива, и из остальных делать перестановки внутри.

Просто хочу найти наиболее оптимальный способ решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, есть граф-треугольник из трёх узлов и трёх рёбер, или циклический список.

Искомые комбинации - просто обходы его в любом направлении с любого узла - получается 6 вариантов. Собственно, их можно выписать вручную.